# Simple ListBoxItem Issue, not sure how to write this into the code correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, foreach, listboxitem

```
  lblSelected.Text = string.Empty; // empty the label that says you already have an item

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSnacktastic.Rows) // check all the items in the grid view
    {
        CheckBox checkItOut = row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as CheckBox; // get the checkbox
        if (checkItOut != null && checkItOut.Checked) // if the checkbox exists and is checked
        {
              bool storeVariable = true; // store a variable that tells us if we need to add it to the list
              **foreach(ListBoxItem listItem in lbSelected.Items)**  // Loop through list box items to see if we already have it. i haven't used listbox in a long time, this might be slightly wrong 
              {
                    // I'm not sure if it's .Text - compare the text of the listbox item to the checkbox item description
                    if(listItem.Text== checkItOut.Text)
                    {
                         lblSelected.Text = "The Item " + listItem.Text + " has already been added."; // make our already have it label
                         storeVariable = false; // remember that we don't need to add this item
                    } 
              }
              if(storeVariable) // if we do need to add this item
              {
                  lbSelected.Items.Add(checkItOut.Text); // create a new list box item with the check box item's description - this code is not complete
               }
        }
    }
}
```

The highlighted (**) area is reading with an error as I am debugging. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm sure this is a simple question to answer, but I am not finding the right information online.

Comment: ListBoxItem has a red squiggly underneath of it.

Comment: Should I just call it ListBox instead?

Comment: Where is lbSelected declared and populated.

Comment: In the design view @TheEdge

Comment: Is it in a template item? Can you post the necessary ASPX code?

Answer (score 0):

Please Change

```
foreach(ListBoxItem listItem in lbSelected.Items)
{

}
```

TO

```
foreach(ListItem listItem in lbSelected.Items)
  {

  }
```

Comment: I changed this, and the squiggly line is gone. However, my select process isn't working. Would you be willing to look at the sample, then my code and see if you can figure out what I'm doing wrong? I don't want to throw links around without permission for reputations sake. @Kiranramchandran

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777191/trying-to-move-checkbox-items-in-gridview-to-listbox-with-a-select-button-meth

I gave a better description here. @Kiranramchandran